# How to substitute a value in a div in a custom dropdown VUE JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good evening everyone, faced such a problem.
When I select a value in the drop-down list, I need to substitute it in the "selected"
How can i do this?

[image]

```
                        <div class=" select__body" v-if="addedForm === 2">
                            <div class="select-item" v-for="businessModel in businessModels" v-bind:key="businessModel.id" v-on:click="businessModelId = businessModel.id; addedForm = false;">
                                {{ businessModel.name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="select-item-nh">
                                <div class="added-form">
                                    <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" class="form-control select-item-add">
                                    <button class="form-control" v-on:click="addModelType('businessModel')">Add to</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-model` to bind the value of selected option's value. [Here is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/13qpbzcn/3/)

Code below is just example and look more carefully at `v-model` and `@change`

```
<div class="select-item" @change="onChange($event)" v-model="key"
v-for="businessModel in businessModels" 
v-bind:key="businessModel.id"
 v-on:click="businessModelId = businessModel.id; 
addedForm = false;">
           {{ businessModel.name }}
</div>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        key: ""
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            console.log(event.target.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

After selecting the value because of the `v-model` the value of `key` become the value of what u selected then you can bind that value into the `box` that you want, for example in your situation you can bind it to the "selected".